# Display inputted TextField's in a different TextArea

Tags: java, eclipse, textfield, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm working with JavaFX and SceneBuilder inside of Eclipse for a class and am having issues with getting a TextField's imputted text (called 'set message') to display in the TextArea (called 'messageArea')

The FXML that handles the TextField and TextArea is

`<TextField fx:id="setMessage" />
<TextArea fx:id="messageArea" prefHeight="112.0" prefWidth="366.0"/>`

The Java that I've been trying to work with is inside of an `if else` statement.

I've set up the

`@FXML private TextField setMesssage
 @FXML private TextArea messageArea`

with my latest attempt being:

`messageArea.setText(setMessage.getText() + "static text to display.");`

My head's been too deep in this and I'm missing something obvious in the logic.

---

An update: 
I've gotten a little further with another idea. I tried attaching the textdisplay to a button the user clicks, and am ALMOST getting it to work. the code is moved out of an `if else`, and instead is inside the buttons class. the code that is displaying text is

`messageArea.setText("text" + messageArea);`

However, while displaying "text" where I want it, the `messageArea` is showing the fxml code instead for some reason.

Comment: You are missing some basic concepts.  I advise writing a small standalone program (approx 20 lines) without FXML which does what you wish.  You can add in FXML once you understand the basic concepts better.  If you are still having issues, you can add your complete basic program to your question as an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You should also better explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I really wish I could do that, and would love to, but this is for a university semester project and my professor is forcing us to use SceneBuilder, and has literally taught us none of it and gave us three weeks to complete it.

I did get the inputted text to appear when I click a button: 

`messageArea.setText(setMessage.getText());`

However now I need to be able to control when it appears. Which would be for another thread I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: hitchhiker]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAppender extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Enter text to be appended.");
        Button append = new Button("Append");
        append.setDefaultButton(true);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setPromptText("Appended text is displayed here.");
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        append.setOnAction(event -> {
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + textField.getText() + "\n");
            textField.clear();
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(
                textField,
                append,
                textArea
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```